# Change each place in a string to find all possible combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, product, python-itertools

The goal is to find all possible combinations if we change one place in a string with some specific characters.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
from itertools import product

string = "abc123"

char = "def2346789"

for i in range(len(string)):
    for char1 in product(char):
        print(string[:i] + char1 + string[i+1:])
```

`char` means characters that will be used in each place.

But I'm confused how it's going to work in the second part, will enjoy to explore the solution.

So the result will be something like this:

```
dbc123 adc123
ebc123 aec123
fbc123 afc123 
2bc123 a2c123 
3bc123 a3c123
4bc123 a4c123
6bc123 a5c123
7bc123 a6c123
8bc123 a7c123
9bc123 a8c123 etc...
```

Comment: Could you clarify which part is the "second part"?

Comment: @Moosefeather for loops

Comment: Can you provide some output example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't (shouldn't) need to use `itertools.product` here. That is probably what is confusing you:

```
string = "abc123"

char = "def2346789"

for i in range(len(string)):
    for c in char:
        print(string[:i] + c + string[i+1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

By the second part, I assume you mean the for loops.

It is basically that:

```
for every character position in string (called i):
    for every character in char (called char1):
        substitute the character at the current position with char1
        #This is done by printing all characters before the current position 
        #(string[:i]), then printing the new character (char1) then printing all 
        #charactrers after the current position (string[i+1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

use a function and a comprehension too make the code more readable

```
     string = "abc123"
     char = "def2346789"

     def fncCombinations(a):
           combination_list=[]
           for j in range(len(string)): 
                combination_list.append(string[:j] + a + string[j+1:])
     return combination_list 
     combination_list=[fncCombinations(a) for a in char]
     print(combination_list)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a stack and queue

```
string="abc123"
char = "def2346789"
queue=[]
stack=[]
combination_list=[]
queue=[x for x in string]
    
for index in range(len(queue)):
    stack.append(queue.pop(0))
    front="".join(stack[:-1])
    back="".join(queue)
    combination_list.append([front+a+back for a in char])

 print(combination_list)
```